# Visual Studio 2013 blurry interface

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Ok this is a really strange problem, when I open a certain project (always the same one and only that one) both the interface and code are quite blurry and honestly kinda painful to look at for long periods of time.

Here is a small example of the blurry one and another project that is much better:

[image: Blurry picture]

[image: Good picture]

As you can see the first picture is blurrier than the second one,

I think the upload compression mitigates a little this problem but you can still see some differences (E.G. look at the icon with a magnifying glass on a folder on the right side). I assure you that in reality they are much much worse, to the point that I can't work on that project anymore without getting a headache. I can't show you images containing code as per company policy but take my word that it's much more noticeable while reading code.

Both projects have been created on the same machine, on the same external screen and about ~1 week of distance one from the other with no updates in between. Also my graphics driver (along with anything else) are up to date.

Since this is not a problem with all the projects but only a specific one I think I may have messed up some settings while changing the project's preferences. Is there an option that i missed that could be the cause of this problem? Maybe something like a resolution scaling?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/a-better-multi-monitor-experience-with-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: @HansPassant well yeah, convincing the higher ups to switch to VS 2019 is not going to happen (2013 works  fine, we need to recompile everything for teh new version and so on). I know that 2019 is much better for multi monitor but what I don't understand is why only that project seem to mess up. I'd be more than happy with a "it just doesn't work for 2013" (it's also another reason I could bring to justify the request for 2019) but before doing that I want to make sure it's not me that messed something up and broke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because my main monitor has a resolution of `1920x1080` while my secondary monitor it's `1920x1200`

The primary monitor defaults to `125%` scaling while the secondary one defaults to `100%`, apparently Visual Studio doesn't like this difference.

Opening VS on the secondary monitor while the primary is at `125%` scaling will have a blurry interface, this persists even when changing the scaling of the primary monitor while VS is still open.

On the other hand opening VS when the primary monitor is set at `100%` scaling will show correctly on the secondary monitor and will keep showing correctly even after changing the scaling of the primary one as long as VS is kept open and not restarted.

This applies to VS 2013 and I don't currently have the means to test it on other versions of VS.